# "not prepared by either .. or" vs. "prepared by neither...nor"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-choice

1. "This substance is not prepared by either the method 1, or the method 2, or the method 3".
2. "This substance is prepared by neither the method 1, nor the method 2, nor the method 3".

Are both of these sentences grammatically correct? Which one is a better choice? Is there a difference in use?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the point of mentioning these methods at all, if ***none*** of them are relevant to the topic (this substance)? But if they all have to be named for some reason, *This substance was not prepared by any of the methods 1, 2, or 3.* Both your versions are syntactically valid - they're just pointlessly verbose.

Comment: Actually, they might *not* be considered verbose in context: the author is making very clear that *each* of these is ineffective for that purpose. Might as well criticize MLKJr "I have a dream" speech for being repetitive.